# Twitter connector on Mule Studio

Tags: twitter, mule

I'm trying to send tweets with a mule application ,but i get a bad credentials error

```
root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Bad credentials
    at org.mule.twitter.TwitterConnector.connect(TwitterConnector.java:165)
    at org.mule.twitter.connectivity.TwitterConnectorConnectionFactory.makeObject(TwitterConnectorConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

It has 4 key accessKey ,accesSecret,consumerKey and consumerSecret , consumerKey and consumerSecret are given when create a twitter app but for accessKey and access secret I have used the email and the password that i used for login in twitter,is it wrong?

Comment: I believe the accessKey and accessSecret are generated when a given user grants authorization to the application, you can get them after creating your Twitter application by creating your "access token".

Comment: I have the same issue, my credentials are completely ok, but it seems to be related to twitter4j not taking my proxy settings into account. Are you behind a proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your Twitter app , please remove the call back url details. This might cause the bad credentials issue.

Also when you create a token be careful to provide it in mule without blank spaces